# Are these statements "truly" equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

Consider a set $A$, elements $x,y$ in $A$ and the following propositions:
\begin{equation}
\exists x\in A\ |\quad x=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\forall x\in A:\quad x=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\forall x\in A,\ \exists y\in A\ |\quad x=y
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\exists x\in A\ |\ \forall y\in A:\quad x=y
\end{equation}
The first three conditions are true for every set, while the last condition implies that $A$, if non empty, has only one element.

My question is this: are there any differences whatsoever between the first three propositions or are they simply interchangheable?

Comment: The first statement is not true for the empty set (I guess there are some symbols missing and the statement is actually $\exists x \in A \mid x = x$, otherwise I don't see what set you're talking about).

Comment: Re the last sentence, thre's no "if non-empty" about it: if the sentence is true in $A$ then $A$ has one and only one element.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, yes, both $x$ and $y$ are actually in $A$ wherever mentioned.

Comment: (I'll edit the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the 2nd and 3rd propositions are equivalent, because they are both universally true, both because of the reflexive property of equivalence, that always $z = z$:

$$\forall x \in A ~ x = x \tag{2}$$
  $$\forall x \in A ~ \top$$ 
  $$\top$$

$$\forall x \in A ~\exists y \in A ~ x = y \tag{3}$$
  $$\forall x \in A ~ x = x\top$$ 
  $$\forall x \in A ~ \top$$ 
  $$\top$$

The first statement is equivalent to saying that $A$ is nonempty because  $\exists x \in A ~ \top$ can only instantiate the $x$ from an element in $A$.

The last statement is equivalent to stating that $A$ has exactly 1 element.

Comment: So essentially there is no "hidden information" among the two equivalent propositions...in other words, they are only symbolically different?

Comment: Logically equivalent, textually different.